# localStorage is somehow mixing up all my numbers

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm creating an extension that is a sticky button on the browser and when clicked it loads the next article you've saved. These articles are stored in a firebase DB and are being fetched on page load.

I've added a pointer variable to index the array and storing the value of the pointer in local storage so I have it as the pages refresh. I'm able to subtract the value of the pointer correctly and when I try to load the next URL upon click for some reason it loads an entirely different URL.

the shape of fetched data:

```
data = [
{
  book: "the matrix,
  url: 'https://thisurl1.com
},
{
  book: "the matrix 2,
  url: 'https://thisurl2.com
},
{
  book: "the matrix 3,
  url: 'https://thisurl3.com
}
]
```

here's the code:

```
// check if local storage is available
const storageAvailable = (type) => {
}

// fetches articles from article endpoint => [data]
const fetchArticles = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("url_endpoint");
    const data = await response.json();
    articleStorage = Object.values(data);
    localStorage.setItem("articles", JSON.stringify(articleStorage))
    const pointer = Number(localStorage.getItem("pointer"));
    if (pointer === null || pointer < 0 || pointer > articleStorage.length - 1) {
      localStorage.setItem("pointer", articleStorage.length - 1);
    }
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

// create the next button
const nextButton = () => {
  // creating tags and buttons
  // styling the button

  // loads next article on click
  button.addEventListener("click", loadNextArticle);

  // appending to dom
};

// loads next article in array
const loadNextArticle = () => {
  const pointer = Number(localStorage.getItem("pointer"));
  const newPointer = pointer - 1;
  const articleStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('articles'));
  if (pointer < 0 || pointer > articleStorage.length - 1) {
    alert('nothing else to show');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('pointer', newPointer);
    window.location.href = articleStorage[newPointer].link;
  }
};

window.onload = () => {
  if (storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("articles") === null) fetchArticles();
    nextButton();
  } else {
    console.log('local storage not available');
  }
};
```

Comment: So what is different? Hard for us to guess. Add console.log() lines and see what changes.

Comment: When you subtract from pointer, you never update the pointer variable....

Answer (score 1):

You never update pointer

```
console.log(pointer); // <-- read pointer
localStorage.setItem("pointer", pointer - 1); // <-- update local storage
if (pointer < 0 || pointer > articleStorage.length - 1) { // <-- still the same pointer value
```

You need to update the variable since it will not update on its own

```
pointer--; // update the variable
localStorage.setItem("pointer", pointer); 
if (pointer < 0 || pointer > articleStorage.length - 1) {
```

Comment: Hi, I added the changes and updates the code above accordingly however I'm still getting random articles rendered. As I click the "next" button it shows the correct article to be rendered, however, on page load it just renders an article at a different pointer value.